Irreducible polynomials with complex root.
I need to show that if $f$ and $g$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$[$x$] and they share a common complex root, then there is $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f = a . g$.
What I thought:
Call $u \in \mathbb{C}$ the root of $f$ and $g$. Therefore, $f(u) = g(u) = 0$.
$\mathbb{Q}$[$x$] is an Euclidean domain, so we can write $f = a . g + r$ and, evaluating for $u$, $f(u) = a(u) . g(u) + r(u)$ $\Rightarrow$ $0 = a(u) .0 + r(u)$ $\Rightarrow$ $r(u) = 0$.
If from this I can conclude that $r=0$, it is easy to conclude that $a$ must be a constant because $f$ is irreducible. But I am not sure how can I justify $r(u) = 0 \Rightarrow r = 0$ since there is nothing about the degree of $g$.

Let $h(x)=\gcd(f,g)$. Since $f$ is irreducible, either $h$ is a unit, or $h$ is an associate of $f$. But it cannot be a unit: if $\gcd(f,g)=1$, then there exist polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $1 = p(x)f(x) + q(x)g(x)$. Evaluating at the common root $c$ of $f$ and $g$, we get $1=0$, which is impossible.
Thus, $h$ must be an associate of $f$, $h=af$ for some nonzero $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. But $h$ also divides $g$, and by a symmetric argument, it must be an associate of $g$, $h=bg$ for some nonzero $b\in\mathbb{Q}$. So $af=bg$, hence $f=\frac{b}{a}g$ with $b,a\in\mathbb{Q}$, as required.

Got it! Many thanks!
